# Workaround for bug in BigQuery Simba JDBC Driver?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

I'm using JetBrains DataGrip and the latest [Simba JDBC driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers#jdbc_release_1521005), version 1.5.2.1005. I'm developing some stored procedures in BigQuery, but hitting what appears to be a bug in the Simba driver.

To replicate the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE performance.bug_test()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE working TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (SELECT GREATEST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()));
        FOR broken IN (SELECT x FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) x)
        DO
            -- no need to do anything
        END FOR;
    END;
CALL performance.bug_test();
```

BigQuery's logs report that it runs successfully, but DataGrip reports an error from the driver:

```
[HY000] [Simba][JDBC](11380) Null pointer exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Calling the proc from the BigQuery console itself also works fine, further suggesting a driver issue.

I set LogLevel to 6 on the driver to get trace output, which yielded more detail:

```
Jan 09 03:41:27.432 INFO  674 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.jobs.JobsGetRequest.execute: executed request jobs.get. id:rm-olympus-dev1-293113:US.script_job_fbb834d49881597fd309b76046f425cf_0, query:SELECT STRUCT<TIMESTAMP>((SELECT GREATEST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))).*;, status:DONE 
Jan 09 03:41:27.433 TRACE 674 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.getJob("rm-olympus-dev1-293113", "script_job_eda20e0cf7d852251b82cb78b6b59153_1"): +++++ enter +++++
Jan 09 03:41:27.433 TRACE 674 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.AbstractRequestWithRetry.executeWithRetry(): +++++ enter +++++
Jan 09 03:41:27.591 INFO  674 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.requests.jobs.JobsGetRequest.execute: executed request jobs.get. id:rm-olympus-dev1-293113:US.script_job_eda20e0cf7d852251b82cb78b6b59153_1, query:SELECT x FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3]) x, status:DONE 
Jan 09 03:41:27.591 TRACE 674 com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQAbstractExecutor.close(): +++++ enter +++++
Jan 09 03:41:27.592 TRACE 674 com.simba.googlebigquery.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSIDataEngine.close(): +++++ enter +++++
Jan 09 03:41:27.592 ERROR 674 com.simba.googlebigquery.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException: [Simba][JDBC](11380) Null pointer exception.
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][JDBC](11380) Null pointer exception.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.processChildJobs(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQSQLExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteStatementImpl.execute(RemoteStatementImpl.java:79)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.ScriptStatistics.getEvaluationKind()" is null
    ... 22 more
```

It seems to me that the driver is fetching execution statistics, but bombs with an NPE when `com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.ScriptStatistics.getEvaluationKind()` returns null -- even though [null is a valid return value](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/ScriptStatistics.html#getEvaluationKind--).

I would normally report this bug to the developers, but I can't for the life of me find anywhere to do so on the Insight Software/Magnitude/Simba forums or support areas.

Has anyone run into this bug already? Are there any workarounds I could employ? I essentially just need to utilize the `FOR iterator IN (query)` functionality, so anything that can easily iterate over query results should work. I can just use the BigQuery console for this proc, but doing so is obviously inconvenient when all other development is taking place in DataGrip.

Comment: Hi @Tim Russell, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.